# How to access UnityEngine in Unity Plugins

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a library for Unity app developers which they can use to do a bunch of logical things on their apps.

**Approach**:

Created a new .NET Class Library solution on VisualStudio Community.

**Problem**:

I need to save some data in PlayerPrefs.

- How can I access UnityEngine classes in my library?
- Am I following the right approach? Or there is another way to create a plugin for Unity in which I can use the UnityEngine classes as well?

PS: Completely new to Unity environment.

Comment: Did you read the official documentation? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html

Comment: Missed the part: At this stage, you will have the option to select the required DLL file. On Mac OS X, the file path is:

Applications/Unity.app/Contents/Managed/UnityEngine.dll

Thanks @UnholySheep